# copy and paste large xml from log file using vi to notepad

Tags: xml, notepad++, copy-paste, vi

I have an xml file having more than 500 lines is  printed to a log file on a unix server. Using VI editor I want to copy the xml from log file and paste it to a notepad++.
I tried using v/V + y commands in vi but when I paste it in notepad no data is pasted.
The otherway I have is copy the lines that fit in screen and paste it, but for a 500 line xml I have to do this multiple times. 
Is there any other way that I can achieve this?!!

Comment: cp /source-path  /destination-path

Answer (score 1):

If you are running notepad++ and vi on different machine (typically through a terminal emulator such as putty), you must copy the text with the mouse. AFAIK, there is no other way.

If you are running vim on Windows or on linux/unix, do as follows:
ggVG"*y

then paste in notepad++.